# how to fill windows exif tags

Tags: java, exif, icafe

Good evening
I want to fill in the jpg photo file windows properties

Apparently these are the exiftags

```
[Exif IFD0] Windows XP Title
[Exif IFD0] Windows XP Author
[Exif IFD0] Windows XP Subject
```

I looked at the side of icafe.jar but have not found these tags.
Can I make it with icafe or other jar library ?

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.icafe4j.image.meta.Metadata;
import com.icafe4j.image.meta.exif.Exif;
import com.icafe4j.image.meta.jpeg.JpegExif;
import com.icafe4j.image.meta.exif.ExifTag;
import com.icafe4j.image.tiff.TiffTag;
import com.icafe4j.image.tiff.FieldType;

fin = new FileInputStream(Fm_filePathIn);
fout = new FileOutputStream(Fm_filePathOut);


List<Metadata> metaList = new ArrayList<Metadata>();
 metaList.add(populateExif(JpegExif.class));

Exif populateExif(Class<?> exifClass) throws IOException {

Exif exif = new JpegExif();

    exif.addImageField(ExifTag.WINDOWS_XP_AUTHOR, FieldType.WINDOWSXP, "Toto");
    exif.addImageField(ExifTag.WINDOWS_XP_KEYWORDS, FieldType.WINDOWSXP, "Copyright;Authorbisou");
// Insert ThumbNailIFD
    // Since we don't provide thumbnail image, it will be created later from the input stream
    exif.setThumbnailRequired(true);

    return exif;
  }


        fin.close();
        fout.close();
```

Comment: Do you have any code that demonstrates how you're using that library?

Comment: this code

with this error (i use javascript in a groovy extension of filemaker)
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: WINDOWS_XP_AUTHOR for class: com.icafe4j.image.meta.exif.ExifTag

Comment: I mean application code, as in the code that resulted in that error. The error alone is only so useful.

Comment: Patience because the code is not passed in the comment also I just put the code in the initial post

Comment: I don't really understand why this question is tagged JavaScript. Your code and the library you are trying to use are java

Comment: The error occurs because these exifstags do not exist in icafe
And that's why I'm looking for another code or another library

Comment: javascript is different ?

Comment: @ericire JavaScript and Java are not the same thing, no.

Comment: ok the tag is on Java.
Any solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those tags do exist in ICAFE but they are not Exiftag. They are TiffTag. Replace the ExifTag with TiffTag, it will work. Look at the TestMetada.java, it clearly shows that.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.icafe4j.image.meta.Metadata;
import com.icafe4j.image.meta.exif.Exif;
import com.icafe4j.image.meta.jpeg.JpegExif;
import com.icafe4j.image.meta.exif.ExifTag;
import com.icafe4j.image.tiff.TiffTag;
import com.icafe4j.image.tiff.FieldType;

public class TestWindowsXP {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(Fm_filePathIn);
    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(Fm_filePathOut);

    List<Metadata> metaList = new ArrayList<Metadata>();

    Exif exif = new JpegExif();

    exif.addImageField(TiffTag.WINDOWS_XP_AUTHOR, FieldType.WINDOWSXP, "Toto");
    exif.addImageField(TiffTag.WINDOWS_XP_KEYWORDS, FieldType.WINDOWSXP, "Copyright;Authorbisou");
    // Insert ThumbNailIFD
    // Since we don't provide thumbnail image, it will be created later from the input stream
    exif.setThumbnailRequired(true);

    metaList.add(exif);
    Metadata.insertMetadata(metaList, fin, fout);

    fin.close();
    fout.close();
 }
}
```

And the following is a screenshot when I right-click the resulting image->show properties. You can see the information you wanted to insert is showing.

[image]

Comment: Excuse me I had not seen your answer.
it works
thank you

Comment: TiffTag.WINDOWS_XP_TITLE and TiffTag.WINDOWS_XP_SUBJECT